# Node Js redirecting to different pages doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I'm running a local server with Node Js. I have couple of completely identical html pages and on every page there is a form with submit. On pressing submit I would like to save the user input and redirect to the next html page. The problem is it only works until the second submit and as soon as you press submit for a third time it gives an error cannot post.

My app.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const log=require('simple-node-logger').createSimpleLogger();
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname +'/images'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('initial.html');
});

app.post('/userID', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.appendFileSync('fileSync', req.body.userID, 'utf8');
  return res.sendfile('first.html');
});

app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.appendFileSync('fileSync', req.body.userID, 'utf8');
  return res.sendfile('second.html');
});

app.post('/submit2', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.appendFileSync('fileSync', req.body.userID, 'utf8');
  return res.sendfile('third.html');
});

app.post('/submit3', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.appendFileSync('fileSync', req.body.userID, 'utf8');
  return res.sendfile('forth.html');
});

app.post('/submit4', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.appendFileSync('fileSync', req.body.userID, 'utf8');
  return res.sendfile('fifth.html');
});
```

My initial.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/userID">
        <input type="text" name="userID" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My first.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit"
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">    
</form>
```

My second.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit2"
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">    
</form>
```

My third.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit3"
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">    
</form>
```

My forth.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit4"
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">    
</form>
```

So it opens without a problem initial.html, first.html, third.html but as soon as it goes to third.html it gives an error "cannot POST /submit3". They are all in the same folder. I'm submitting an array of user chosen values from select tags (but this part works, so I haven't included it).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This might not be completely related to the problem, but the HTML in your files `first.html` and `second.html` (and the other two as well) is incorrect. You're not closing the initial `form` element - you're missing an `>` at the end of the line. See your `initial.html` for a correct syntax.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you're new here, but I want to compliment you on the effort in writing this question. It is a clear and complete question, focussed on your problem, and although the resolution will be trivial -- you just don't know that yet -- it shows respect to SO to make such an elaborate write-up. Kudos to you.

Comment: Do not use blocking `synchronous` code without a valid reason. Maximum use `asynchronous io`